# How to insert a key value pair on a list and write on a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im new to Python and I have been given a task for the company's HRIS. So I have written a code from a raw .csv file that will be re-written by filtering all other data and make sure that the first instance of IN and OUT of a person will be listed. How can I insert or append the time-in of a person on a list on the very same row?

```
employeeInfo2 = {'Name': employeeName, 'Date': employeeDate, 'Status': employeeStatus}
        if employeeInfo2 not in employeeProfile:
            employeeProfile.append(employeeInfo2)
```

when i tried putting this line of code just below the above code, the time is displayed as a new line in the csv file or is written on a new row.

```
employeeProfile.append({'Time': employeeTime})
```

```
import csv
import string
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import OrderedDict

employeeProfile = []
with open('newDTR.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    employee = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

    for employeeList in employee:
        stringDate = employeeList['Date/Time']
        employeeName = employeeList['Name']
        employeeStatus = employeeList['Status']
        dateTimeObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringDate,  '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        employeeDate = dateTimeObject.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        employeeTime = dateTimeObject.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        parsedTimeOut = parse(employeeTime)
        expected = parsedTimeOut + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
        timeOut = expected.time()
        employeeInfo2 = {'Name': employeeName, 'Date': employeeDate, 'Status': employeeStatus}
        if employeeInfo2 not in employeeProfile:
            employeeProfile.append(employeeInfo2)


with open('fixedDTR.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as new_csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Date', 'Status', 'Time', 'Expected Time Out']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for b in employeeProfile:
        print(b)
        csv_writer.writerow(b)
```

I was expecting that employeeTime will be aligned to each line of data but is not. Probably because the employeeProfile.append({'Time': employeeTime}) is on a new line. What should be the best approach?

[image: output file]

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at your code, there isnt and insert for Time as you are writing b from employeeProfile.

Simply put when you use csv_write.writerow(b), this will automatically go down 1 row in the csv file. You could append your time key to the dict stored in employeeprofile.

```
employeeInfo2 = {'Name': employeeName, 'Date': employeeDate, 'Status': employeeStatus}

if employeeInfo2 not in employeeProfile:
            employeeInfo2["Time"] = employeeTime # or whatever you wanted in the field 
            employeeProfile.append(employeeInfo2)
```

This would add the Time column to your dict, which would then be written nicely by csv_writer.writerow.

Based on your output I am guessing you are writing the time after like this:

```
csv_writer.writerow(b) 
csv_writer.writerow(times)
```

where times is your dict for the Times. which causes the offset since writerow adds a newline to each line of your csv.

Comment: Hello @jason. nope that's not my approach. All logic happens in the 
``` 
if employeeInfo2 not in employeeProfile:
            employeeProfile.append(employeeInfo2)
```
I didnt double the csv_write.

Anyway, tried your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: Your code does not indicate when and where the Time field is being written to the csv. Could you expand on that? The csv_writer.writerow() function is pretty well documented so there shouldn't be any mismatch in terms of the row for the Time field and the rest. Your append is appending to the list of items in employeeProfile. -> [eployeeInfo2,{time: time}] when you iterate it goes through as a second write. Employeeprofile2's dict should be expanded for Time rather than appending to the list. Ive made a few corrections that should work if you want the logic to be after the if condition

Comment: You can confirm my statement by watching your print(b) output. With your current solution you will get:

{'Name': employeeName, 'Date': employeeDate, 'Status': employeeStatus}
{'Time': employeeTime}

Comment: @jariusjames Any news?

Comment: Hi @jason. I still cannot make it to work. Still thinking of other ways... If you have email I can send you the file and the code that i've tried.

Comment: one of my purpose on creating this program is to eliminate redundancy of TIME-IN of an employee's logs. so my approach is to print only the first instance of TIMEIN and TIMEOUT in that file. Using your code above, it still prints the unwanted TIME-INs because the time are different thus, this part of the code `if employeeInfo2 not in employeeProfile:` returns true.

Comment: @jariusjames Okay could you post up a dummy csv source file that you are using to get the Time-ins/Time out? Based on your explanation, it would be quite simple to implement a logic that takes first TIME-IN and ignore the others as well as to take the last TIMEOUT. So please correct me if I am misunderstanding your process. 1) you are parsing some data from some csvfile to python, which then writes it into another csvfile with status indicating if it is a TIMEIN or TIMEOUT: and you want to do some other processing with that later to get the first TIMEIN and TIMEOUT?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, I would recommend using pandas and then handling the data there, its much more cleaner than writing to multiple csv files. Also what was misbehaving about the solution I posted? Could you update me about what went wrong?

Comment: So the answer is solving your problem?